# Can anyone suggest some useful tutorials for developing websites with umbraco?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, umbraco

I need to develop asp.net web application using umbraco cms and iam a beginner to it too.As a part of it,iam looking for a learning resource which would help me learn to develop asp.net application using umbraco cms right from the scratch..

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: There is a Udemy beginner course - https://www.udemy.com/umbraco-beginner/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at:

1. [Video](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/) Tutorial.
2. [Building Your First Umbraco Site From Scratch](http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2010/5/13/building-your-first-umbraco-site-from-scratch)

Answer (score 3):

Few Links here:
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/umbraco-absolute-beginner-tutorial

This has a few links from it you may find helpful
http://umbracocms.blogspot.com/2010/08/guide-to-umbraco-cms-for-beginners.html

Some Video tutorials from Umbraco though for a small fee
http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/

Once you have looked at the beginner tutorials your best option is going to be first identify the features your web application needs and then do google searches of 'How do i do xxxxxxxxx in umbraco' etc  and work from there.

I find its much easier to learn something like this when you are working on a project and the things you are learning are relevant to you, rather than just following beginners tutorials